# Alter table with casting

Tags: mysql, alter-table, cast

Is there a way of run an `alter table` command with cast on MySQL databases?

I know that is possible to do it with Postgresql and Sql servers, but I didn't find anything about it when searching the documentation..

My database is very large and I want to convert Decimal to BigInt, so I'm trying to do it with a single command and avoid workarounds..

Comment: If you want to avoid conversion errors - run, in the same transaction, `UPDATE my_table SET my_value = CEIL (or FLOOR) (my_value);` depending on your requirements. Not sure if column mods can be part of a transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a single statement.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE T (val decimal(18,3));
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO T VALUES (1.25);
> INSERT INTO T VALUES (12.526);
> INSERT INTO T VALUES (1000.25);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT val FROM T;
> ```
>
> ```
> |      val |
> | -------: |
> |    1.250 |
> |   12.526 |
> | 1000.250 |
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE T MODIFY COLUMN val bigint;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM T;
> ```
>
> ```
> |  val |
> | ---: |
> |    1 |
> |   13 |
> | 1000 |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=262ca808f336f4d9db59d24ffd19a462)*

Comment: But, did you want the values to be rounded off??